# Common varnish: difference between beresp & resp, bereq & req; req.ttl & beresp.ttl

Tags: caching, varnish

Tell me please, whats the difference between these concepts? I didn't found any answers in documentations of Varnish. They just operative these concepts, nothing more.

And what is better to use for caching: beresp.ttl or max-age in Cache-control header?

If you can do it with little examples - do it please :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**req:** The request values as soon as it arrive at Varnish.

**bereq:** The request that goes to the backend. All variables from *req* are automatically assigned to *bereq*. However, those values may slightly differ, because Varnish may modify client requests. For example, HEAD requests coming from clients may be converted to GET requests towards the backend.

**beresp:** The backend respose. Any changes in *beresp* affect *resp* and *obj* which is the cached object. ***Tip:*** If you want to get any additional info to your object, set it to *beresp*.

**resp:** The response that is delivered to the client. All the *beresp* values are passed on to *resp*.

After all the names explained it is elementary to conclude that **req.ttl** is the TTL received from the request and it means nothing unless you configure it differently. **beresp.ttl** is the one that is going to set the TTL of your object.

As about the what's best for caching, Varnish already gets the max-age and sets it to beresp.ttl. So in the end there's no difference. The difficulty of employing this is that some web apps do not treat the *max-age* correctly and end up always sending `nocache` causing Varnish to cache nothing. In those cases you should ignore what comes in beresp.http.cache-control and set your own TTL.

Some relevant reading to deepen further in this topic can be found in the [Varnish Book subroutines section](http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Basics.html#variables-in-vcl-subroutines).

Comment: "end up always sending nocache causing Varnish to cache nothing" - or maybe unset it and set my Cache-control, right?
And can more detail about req.ttl? Because you wrote "it means nothing unless you configure it differently". What did you mean about this?
In the rest, thanks very much, exhaustive answer.

Comment: You're right. 

An about req.ttl, it comes from the requester and it is not something set by your app or Varnish and most of times it should be ignored unless you want your requester to be able to set the object ttl.

Comment: unless you want your requester to be able to set the object ttl - the main thing which I wanted to understand :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You can get a detailed over view about vcl objects from here

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.6/users-guide/vcl-variables.html